# React pagination without JSX

Tags: javascript, json, dom, react.js, pagination

I've published [my first react project](https://github.com/alexjolig/react-pagination-without-jsx/tree/39869afe4063541be9459ec413fab96467cb84e5) for pagination purposes. It's likely I'm making mistakes or there are any improvements to my code. I'd appreciate if anyone has any offers.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 /*
    Simple project to implementing pagination with React
    Developer: Alex Jolig

    Licence:MIT
    Source:https://github.com/alexjolig/react-pagination-without-jsx
    Contact me if you need to: alex.jolig@gmail.com

 */

 class ImageGallery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        posts: [], //However its not relevant in this sample but I named the array posts. feel free to name it as you wish
        currentPage: 1,
        postsPerPage: 5
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);
  }

  //put AJAX request in componentDidMount() method
  componentDidMount() {

    $.ajax({
      url: "generated.json",
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({posts: data});
        console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error("", status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    }); 
  }

    //Handle click on page number list
    handleClick(event) {
        this.setState({
          currentPage: Number(event.currentTarget.id) //using event.target would reference to child tag (a). So use event.currentTarget 
        }); 
    }

    //Handle next and previous buttons
    changePage(event) {
        let newPage = 1;
        if(event.currentTarget.id === 'p-page') {
            newPage = this.state.currentPage > 1 ? this.state.currentPage - 1 : 1;
            this.setState({
              currentPage: newPage
            });
        }
        else {
            let pageCount = this.state.posts.length / this.state.postsPerPage;          
            newPage = this.state.currentPage < pageCount ? this.state.currentPage + 1 : pageCount;
            this.setState({
              currentPage: newPage
            });         
        }
    } 

    render() {

        const { posts, currentPage, postsPerPage } = this.state;

        // Logic for displaying current posts
        const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
        const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
        const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);        

        const renderPosts = currentPosts.map((post, index) => {
            return React.createElement('li', {key: post.index},
              React.createElement('h2', {}, post.name),
              React.createElement('a', {href: post.phone}, post.phone)
            )
        });     

        // Logic for displaying page numbers
        const pageNumbers = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage); i++) {
          pageNumbers.push(i);
        }

        const prevPage = React.createElement(
            'li', { className: 'page-item',
                    key:'p-page',
                    id: 'p-page',
                    onClick: this.changePage
                },
            React.createElement('a', {  className: 'page-link',
                                        href: '#'
                                    }, 'Previous'
            )
          );

        const nextPage = React.createElement(
            'li', { className: 'page-item',
                    key:'n-page',
                    id: 'n-page',
                    onClick: this.changePage
                },
            React.createElement('a', {  className: 'page-link',
                                        href: '#'
                                    }, 'Next'
            )
          );          

        const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
          return React.createElement(
            'li', { className: 'page-item' + (currentPage === number ? ' active' : '') ,
                    key:number,
                    id: number,
                    onClick: this.handleClick
                },
            React.createElement('a', {  className: 'page-link',
                                        href: '#'
                                    }, number
            )
          );
        }); 

        //NOTE: return elements as array is added in react 16+
        return [
                React.createElement('div', {key: 'a', className: 'row'},
                    React.createElement('ul', {key:'a'}, renderPosts)
                ),
                React.createElement('div', {key: 'b', className: 'row'},
                                        React.createElement('ul', {className: 'pagination',key: 'b'}, 
                                        prevPage,
                                        renderPageNumbers,
                                        nextPage)   
                )                   
            ];
    }
 }

    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(ImageGallery, null),
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I recommend you to use JSX and build tools because they are totally awesome!*

People use npm and bundlers (like Webpack) because loading each library separately makes the page significantly slower. [Let me show you an extreme example. Feel free to take a peek at the source code.](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html) And that's not to mention that it's simpler to update my libraries using npm.

JSX can help you effortlessly construct the element tree in React. You're missing out a lot if you avoid JSX!

You can create an alias for `React.createElement` to make your code more readable.

```
const h = React.createElement;
```

> //NOTE: return elements as array is added in react 16+

You're right. Did you know that React 16 also has [a cooler feature](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)?

If you used Fragments, you wouldn't need to add keys to the two `div`s you rendered in the `render()` method.

Here's the improved code:

```
return h(React.Fragment, null,
    h("div", { className: "row" },
        h("ul", null, renderPosts)
    ),
    h("div", { className: "row" },
        h("ul", { className: "pagination" }),
        prevPage,
        renderPageNumbers,
        nextPage
    )
)
```

You don't need to pass `null` as the second parameter here:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(ImageGallery, null),
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```
ReactDOM.render(h(ImageGallery), document.getElementById("root"))
```

You don't need to use `jQuery(document).ready` when you've already put your `<script>` tags under the container element.

The React community prefers using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) to fire AJAX requests because:

- `fetch` is a Promise-based API for fetching resources, it is built in every major web browser out there.
- `axios` is a small library that does only one thing and does it well, as opposed to jQuery which tries to be the library to do everything web-related.

Two last things:

- Fix indentation. Or use [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) and forget about it completely.
- Remove all of the comments in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the heads ups. I'll try changing AJAX request to one of your offers. But the reason I wanted to do it without JSX is that I don't want to have to work with npm and stuffs when I'm going to use just a small component like this in a single page. I couldn't find any ways to use JSX without using npm.

Comment: You are right, if you are only using React for a small component on a large non-React web app then using JSX and build tools only adds overhead. And no, I am not giving you any heads up! ;P

Comment: I've published the professional version of my pagination and used your ideas. Thank you. [Professional pagination using react](https://github.com/alexjolig/Professional-pagination-using-react-without-JSX)